# Using HttpClient to Submit a GraphQL Request c#

Tags: c#, graphql

I am trying to send a GraphQL Query with Arguments, over the Normal HTTP Client in C# and not the GraphQL HttpClient Wrapper. (C# .net 6)

Currently I have a QueryString Written as Follows.

```
"{\"query\" : query{newsPosts(newsBoardID:\"b20b8e89-97d3-480b-88a3-a49a5fe7d5ed\"){post}}}\""
```

however, the Server is Returning an Error `"{\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"The query field must be a string or null.\",\"locations\":[{\"line\":1,\"column\":12}],\"extensions\":{\"code\":\"HC0011\"}}]}"`

I am able to query this API with success from the hotCholoclate Web UI.

Is there something I am missing ?

Help or assistance would be appreciated.